# How to experiment with permalink structure on a select number of posts

Tags: permalinks, redirect

If I wanted to experiment with a new permalink structure on select posts, would creating a list of 301 redirects be the best route to take?

I shouldn’t have to touch that 301 list when I want to flip the switch and enable that same structure for the rest of my posts as long as I ensure that the primary category for each post being redirected is the category being included in the redirect target.

Answer (score 0):

You can alter your permalink structure individually when editing the post or create a custom post type and define your permalink structure in the settings.

[Custom Post Types](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types)